# Show resque-scheduler tab in resque-web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I followed all [instructions on resque-scheduler repo](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) to show up the "Delayed" and "Schedule" tabs on the resque-web interface, but nothing!

Here's the imported gems:

```
gem 'resque', '~> 1.25.2', require: 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 2.5.5'
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web'
```

To normally add scheduler to resque-web, I edited the `./config/initializers/resque_config.rb`

```
require 'resque'
Resque.redis = "127.0.0.1:6379" # tell Resque where redis lives
# This will "normally" make the tabs show up.
require 'resque_scheduler' # the one provided on the README doesn't exist 'resque-scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server' # the one provided on the README doesn't exist 'resque/scheduler/server'
```

To load resque-web, I have used a rails route:

```
ResqueWeb::Engine.eager_load!
mount ResqueWeb::Engine => "/resque_web"
```

But still, no effect on resque web interface...

Answer (score 9):

There is a discussion about this [in the issue tracker](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/301).

Essentially, it seems I need to use the built-in Sinatra app, not 'resque-web'.  If you mount the app like this:

```
require 'resque/scheduler/server'
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => '/resque'
```

Rather than this:

```
mount ResqueWeb::Engine => '/resque'
```

...it should work.

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

I've just made a gem that does this: https://github.com/mattgibson/resque-scheduler-web

Load it in your gemfile with:

```
gem 'resque-scheduler-web'
```

That should be all you need to make the tabs show up when mounting the `ResqueWeb::Engine`.